# How to detect keydown anywhere on page in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keypress

I am trying to detect a key press anywhere on the page in an app built with React.

I remember it being quite easy in jQuery, but I wanted to see if it could be done in React. I didn't want to make a 'frankenstein' project i.e. have some parts in react and some parts in jQuery, if at all avoidable.

So far I have:

```
export default function App() {
    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
    }

    return (
        <div
            onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
            tabIndex="0"
        >
            <Header page_num={100}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But it only seems to work when a user clicks on the actual div in the page, then presses a key.

I want the key press to be detected without the user having to click anywhere on the page.

Comment: Well they have to click on the page for it to be focused, but you should be using https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/ to bind an event on the document.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` hook to achieve this and adding an event listener to `document`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default ({ name }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleKeyDown(e) {
      console.log(e.keyCode);
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

    // Don't forget to clean up
    return function cleanup() {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    }
  }, []);

  return <div>Keydown</div>;
};
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ddrk9w) in action.

Assuming the `<div>` is focused via `tabindex` or similar, you'd be able to see see in the keydown handler that `e.target` would be the `<div>`. You can also wrap the functionality in another component and in it's keydown handler check if the keydown was executed on that element instead of outside using [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).

Here is another [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5wv5iw) that uses `contains` to check if the event target is within the div `ref`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function Hello({ onKeyDown }) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleKeyDown(e) {
      // check if keydown was contained in target div
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }

      // Emit event to parent component
      onKeyDown(e);
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

    return function cleanup() {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={ref} tabIndex="0">
      foo bar baz
    </div>
  );
}

export default Hello;
```

Hopefully that helps!