# How do I create SyntheticEvent listener on the document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the website I'm currently developing, native events (regular `KeyboardEvents`) produce unwanted behaviour (using old versions of state and refs), whilst [`SyntheticEvents`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) (which I believe are `React.KeyboardEvents`) work flawlessly. I'm trying to put a `SyntheticEvent` `onKeyDown` listener on the `document` (so that the keypress can be handled no matter where the focus is), is there any way to achieve this? To work around this, I've made a wrapper element across the whole app with a `onKeyDown` listener, this does not work well though, because it does not register all the presses (such as when a hamburger menu or a full screen photo is focused, which I think happens due to their absolute/fixed positioning).

Example of using `document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown)`, which fires native element, but has incorrect behaviour (`handleKeyDown` uses outdated refs), but registers keypresses globally:

- Stack Trace: [image: Stack trace of addEventListener]
- Event Type: [image: Event type addEventListener]

Example of using app wrapper in which `handleKeyDown` works correctly (the refs are current), probably because it is a `SyntheticEvent`. It does not register clicks globally though:

- Stack Trace: [image: Stack trace of app wrapper]
- Event Type: [image: Event type of app wrapper]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect keydown anywhere on page in a React app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740073/how-to-detect-keydown-anywhere-on-page-in-a-react-app)